# Compile single static library for Cortex M3, M4, M23 and M33

Tags: gcc, linker, cortex-m

I'm currently working on a rather generic communication stack. It gets bytes in on one end, parses the packet and calls a callback.
I want to have this stack in a static library (i.e. `libcommstack.a`).

The library is aimed towards embedded ARM Cortex-M devices. At the moment we have specified that at least a Cortex-M3 should be used (but it should also work for an M4 or M33).

Right now I'm integrating it into another application to verify that linking it is possible. In the future the idea is that we will ship this `.a` file to customers so they can build their application around it, without having direct access to our sources (to encapsulate our IP).

We are using GCC ARM v7.2.1 to compile both the library and the application that is linked to it.
The application I'm trying to integrate it with is compiled for a Cortex M33 with `-mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu-fpv6-sp-d16`.

The code for the library does *not* use any floating points and is compiled using `-march=archv7-m` (both have the `-mthumb` flag).

Linking seemed to all go well, until I actually called a function from the lib. At that point the linker starts to complain:

```
application.elf uses VFP register arguments, libcommstack.a(somefile.c.obj) does not
failed to merge target specific data of file libcommstack.a(somefile.c.obj)
```

Since I'm not using floating points in the library and I don't know (upfront) if the target application does or does not have an FPU (or even uses floats), I'm not sure how to approach this.
I figured there would be two approaches:

1. Compile a single version of the lib, using an instruction set that all of the microcontrollers understand. I was hoping that this would be the case with ARMv7 (although I'm not yet 100% confident that the M23/M33 also support this).
2. Compile a lot of different libs for the different flavors based on the different architectures, FPU, etc.

As you can imagine, I would prefer to keep it simple and go for option 1, but I'm not sure how to "convince" the linker to link these two (or perhaps how to convince the compiler NOT to care about floating points for the lib).

Does anyone know if option 1 is feasible and how it can be achieved?

If it is not feasible, what would be the variables to keep in mind to determine the different build flavors?

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know if option 1 is feasible

Well, feasible, probably.

> how it can be achieved?

Get all the processors you want to support and determine the instructions sets available on all these processors. Then compile for that instruction set.

But, please don't, that is a workaround.

> If it is not feasible, what would be the variables to keep in mind to determine the different build flavors?

Gcc has something like "multilib profiles". See `arm-none-eabi-gcc --print-multi-lib` output. If you have newlib installed, you can go to `/usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/` and see the directories there - newlib is compiled for each profile and installs separate library for it and different library is picked up depending on configuration. Compile for each of those profiles, and package your library by putting libraries in proper `/usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/proper/directory/here` and compiler will pick them up by itself (see `gcc -v` output for library search paths). For an example search newlib sources where it happens, can't find it. ([Here's my example](https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/yio/-/blob/master/pkg/archlinux/PKGBUILD-arm-none-eabi-yio#L35)). With cmake as a backend as a example  you could compile and install as follows:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc --print-multi-lib |
while IFS=';' read -r dir opts; do
     cmake -B builddir CMAKE_C_FLAGS="$opts" CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR="$dir"
     cmake --build builddir
     cmake --install builddir --prefix "/usr/arm-none-eabi/"
done
```